# Does setting a pointer to NULL imply no references to the previous value?

Tags: c, pointers, stack, cpu-registers

Suppose I have a function that looks like this:

```
void fun() {
    struct bintree {
        struct bintree * left;
        struct bintree * right;
    };

    // build a perfectly balanced 7-node bintree
    struct bintree * root = malloc(sizeof(struct bintree));

    root->left = malloc(sizeof(struct bintree));
    root->right = malloc(sizeof(struct bintree));

    root->left->left = malloc(sizeof(struct bintree));
    root->left->right = malloc(sizeof(struct bintree));

    root->right->left = malloc(sizeof(struct bintree));
    root->right->right = malloc(sizeof(struct bintree));

    // create a stack pointer to the left subtree of root
    struct bintree * RL = root->left;

    // remove pointer to root node from stack
    root = NULL;

    // could it be possible to find pointers to root, root->right and
    // its children on the stack/registers? 
}
```

My (naive) assumption is that if I searched the entire stack and registers for addresses to the root node, root->right and its children (on the heap) right before fun returns, I would find none. Is this a fair assumption? If so, could there be exceptions for any architecture that you can think of? How would that happen?

Comment: I knew I would forget something.

Comment: OK. *now* as written you'll at least compile. You assumption of previous address values not being present in memory or somewhere on the stack is at-best platform-specific. In a language-purist perspective, you shouldn't need to care. As written you're definitely leaking memory. The runtime-libary likely has your allocations in a heap-chain somewhere, but without diving into the specifics of your platform once you lose the only reference to a memory address it is "unreachable" as far as your code is concerned.

Comment: Remember, C has no garbage collection - you've forgotten to `free` `root`,  `root->left`, `root->left->left`, and `root->left->right`

Comment: @Eric I didn't free them by intention, as it's not relevant to the question. I probably should have been more clear about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong for most platforms and environments. Data values can be kept in some registers or stack cells even if they aren't anymore from those ones. It's fully compiler's responsibility to put proper values in registers and cells according to the used calling convention and to comply with the required functionality, but nothing more is guaranteed. That's why e.g. local variables are filled with garbage on function entry: they keep some previous values, not cleared after some work finished.

Some tasks require data cleaning (e.g. deleting password contents after its applying) but this is done using explicitly coded cleaning of memory regions.

If you are thinking on languages with garbage collecting, that's another but similar story.

Comment: Thank you. This is the kind of answer I was looking for. I was thinking about garbage collection actually, but in C. More specifically the mark-sweep algorithm and how it would mark objects as not free, assuming it searched the stack and registers for pointers. But we need not get into that as I understand it's more complicated that the posed question.

Comment: @Max It's unlikely that such values will be kept in registers and on stack for a long time. There are so-called conservative garbage collectors which treat each value in checked memory regions as possible pointer. They are statistically good, provided one agree that some objects won't be gathered due to such false positives, but that's a few percent of all objects in memory.